# Magento : Customer Not Able to Login

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login, paypal-express

Recently I upgrade one website from 1.8.1.0 to 1.9.4.0.
Everything working fine into the website accept one issue.

I face strange issue,
The customer who make the payment using "Paypal Express Checkout" are not able to login into the website.

After successfully make the payment for the order, customer register sucessfully.

Now when they try to login with credential, they are not able to login into the website.

There is not any error on page, log file or etc.

Comment: you means customers who purchase as guest and there account created but they are not able to login, correct?

Comment: if this is the case then, And this is happening for customers who pay using paypal express then you must check whether the account created for those customers or not.

Comment: How does the guest customer get created? Is there a step for them to enter a password?

Comment: @Knight017 Yes customer created successfully and if we reset the password from the admin, then they are able to login successfully.

Comment: that means there is some error in setting password while creating user after order, your temporary work around can be reset password programattically after user creation till you find the error. If you share your code of creating user it would more helpful.